# A question regarding DB Images -

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A Clarification, if I have a table that has the following fields....

ProductCategoryID, CategoryName, Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4 and Image5 have data types varbinary(MAX) and ImageMimeType has data type varchar(50). What would be the difference if I have two tables as the following...

(for simplicity sake)
Table One - 
ProductCategoryID, 
CategoryName

Table Two - 
ProductCategoryID, 
ImageID, 
Image1, 
Image2, 
Image3, 
Image4 
Image5 
ImageMimeType

I read somewhere images should be placed in separate table for performance & corruption prevention. Or it doesn't matter? Is there pro's & cons? I am using ASP.NET MVC3 C#, SQL SERVER 2008R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are large, consider configuring your database to store files using Filestream.  That may make a big difference.  Having the image columns in different tables won't matter then, because they'll be stored in different a filegroup.  That said, you should always normalize as you see fit.  Some info on Filestream:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109(v=sql.100).aspx
http://www.aghausman.net/sql_server/configure-sql-server-2008-for-file-stream-2.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Comment: each file are about 126KB. So I don't think I need to have a separate table. Which is a relief, I suppose. Thanks Milimetric.